# Smallest and largest number in any array

Tags: arrays

We can find the largest and smallest number in a sorted integer array very easily. But, how can we find them in an unsorted integer array? Any explanation or code, please.
Thank you.

Comment: you need to explore the full array. try it using `loops` and `conditions` in the language that your are using

Comment: Without using functions for this purpose, the only way is to compare each individual array element to determine the largest and smallest.

Comment: Not really a question for this site, since we're focused on code. That said, the usual method to find the max is to set a variable to the minimum possible value then step through the array and update the variable each time an element holds a value higher than its current value. The minimum search is similar and left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

that's easy if it's a simple array. you can step all element and compare them one-by-one using time complexity: O(n)

e.g.

```js
var array = [ 76 ,5,6,2,199, 20 ];
var smallest = array[0]
var greastest = array[0];
array.forEach( function (value) {
    if(value < smallest)
        smallest = value;

    if(value > greastest){
        greastest = value;
    }
}) 

console.log(smallest,greastest);
```